# standard way of communicating across processes (possibly over network)

Tags: c#, tcp, ipc, tcpclient

I have a project I work on with a friend. its made of a few independent components that together make up a system of 10-20klines. we did this because separating the processes onto different computers in the future might be useful

currently the processes communicate using pretty crude tcp messages through `tcpclient` and `tcplistener`. as in

recieve message -> if the string matches one of the messages we use -> run the function

there isn't really much of a format to our messages and we just work with the string itself. I was wondering what a more typical approach to this communication would be. im sure there's some convenient tools that can pass and generate objects and whatnot, but for example something like json seems like a bit overkill given we mostly communicate control with a very small amount of data

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a good use-case for WCF Service With TCP binding.

Have a look at WCF and TCP Binding on a Windows Service(WCF can be hosted on other process types also)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx

You could also use MSMQ over TCP to do this. See the example below:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/04/29/clear-the-way-msmq-coming-through.aspx

For .NET 2.0 or below, you have .NET Remoting

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Remoting